# SSL certification for my webpage nginx

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean

How i can take ssl certification for my website. Right now it is like http. I want to change it to https. How i can do this. Is it possible in free of cost, without any security issues.

Please some one help me

Comment: i am not sure but may this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-ubuntu-14-04)  can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its possible.

Please follow the below link, it will help you a lot.

https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: It doesn't lacks in security issues? Please confirm me once. Thanks!

Comment: According to my knowledge and understanding. It doesn't lacks in any terms and It gives you 3 months of free certification and you need to renew it after every three months or you can implement cron jobs too

Answer (score 7):

If you have server for your website and you can access to console please follow steps in this link 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04.

Otherwise you must reach to your host company for providing SSL certificate.

Don't worry while using letsencript, it is free and secure.

Comment: Thanks for the info @adil-karaöz

Answer (score 2):

check out lets encrypt

if you're using apache on server then these 2 commands will help you easily

```
# certbot installation
sudo apt-get install python-certbot-apache

#auto configure for apache
certbot --apache -d domain.com
```

Answer (score 1):

check this tutorial [Link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-commercial-certificate-authority). All installations and configurations are provided..